# How to use one foreign key for two models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here is my migration file

```
class CreateTestRevisions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :test_revisions do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :test_id
      t.integer :question_id
      t.integer :test_type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I have two models: `OnlineTest` & `AllindiaTest`.

How can I relate the `t.integer :test_id` to these two models?

Comment: What kind of associations do you want ? what is the situation here? What is the relation between online-test and allindia-test?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a polymorphic association like this:

```
class OnlineTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_revisions, as: :testable
end

class AllindiaTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_revisions, as: :testable
end

class TestRevision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :testable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And make sure you have two columns in `test_revisions` table:

```
testable_id: integer
testable_type: string
```

`testable_id` will store id of `OnlineTest` or `AllindiaTest`.
`testable_type` will store `OnlineTest` or `AllindiaTest` string.

So if you have a `test_devision`, you can use `test_devision.testable` to get `OnlineTest` or `AllindiaTest`, depend on `testable_type`.

More information about [Polymorphich assocication](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreign_key` option to specify the same key for two models like:

```
class TestRevision < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :online_test, foreign_key: :test_id
  belongs_to :allindia_test, foreign_key: :test_id
end
```

Or the best way I think is to treat both of these objects as one through `delegate`:

```
delegate :allindia_test, to: :online_test
```

This way, you only need to have one association: `online_test`, and when you call, `allindia_test`, the call will be delegated to `online_test`.

## Edit:

Well, if you would like to have two different relations, you would need two different ids in that case: `online_test_id` & `all_india_test_id`.

```
class TestRevision < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :online_test
  belongs_to :all_india_test
end
```

Comment: And what will happen when the `OnlineTest` `id` is 1 and the `AllIndiaTest` `id` is also 1. How will you identify the difference?

Comment: If this is the case, then you need to have two different ids in your table: `online_test_id`, and `all_india_test_id`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I differ them with t.integer :test_type, which means if it is OnlinTest the  test_type   is '1' or if is All India Test the test type is '2'

Comment: I'm not getting the big picture. Edit your question, and try to put every there. What models you have right now, with what relations, and what you want out of them.